# No se puede obtener a información del paquete a instalar en pfsense

Tags: php, javascript, linux, ubuntu, pfsense

El error que se muestra es

> UNABLE TO RETRIEVE PACKAGE INFORMATION

la version de pfsense que estoy utilizando es la 2.4.3, trato de instalar un paquete en especifico y me sale eso, pero hasta ahora nada funciona, intente instalar paquetes por medio del shell del pfsense pero no me lo permite tampoco,... y el error que arroja en el shell es

> unable to update package

[image: Captura del mensaje de error]

ya he intentado hasta cambiar de maquina virtual.

Comment: agrega el mensaje del error para saber que dice, pues en la imagen no es legible, segundo lee [ask]

Comment: si, el error es "unable to retrieve package information", es como un bug del pfsense

Comment: si, el error es "unable to retrieve package information", es como un bug del pfsense

Comment: @Aprendiz la pregunta estaba mal formateada por eso no veías el mensaje de error

Comment: Tienes que configurar correctamente la WAN, con la finalidad de que PFSense tenga claro por donde descargar los paquetes que quieres instalar.

Comment: debes ya tener acceso a internet antes de iniciar el pfSense